# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(n / 3) + T(2n / 3) + n^2?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, recurrence

I have been trying to solve a recurrence relation.

The recurrence is `T(n) = T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n^2`

I solved the the recurrence `n` i got it as `T(n)=nT(1)+ [ (9/5)(n^2)( (5/9)^(log n) ) ]`

Can anyone tell me the runtime of this expression?

Answer (score 3):

I think this recurrence works out to Θ(n<sup>2</sup>). To see this, we'll show that T(n) = Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) and that T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Showing that T(n) = Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) is pretty straightforward - since T(n) has an n<sup>2</sup> term in it, it's certainly Ω(n<sup>2</sup>).

Let's now show that T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>). We have that

> T(n) = T(n / 3) + T(2n / 3) + n<sup>2</sup>

Consider this other recurrence:

> S(n) = S(2n / 3) + S(2n / 3) + n<sup>2</sup> = 2S(2n / 3) + n<sup>2</sup>

Since T(n) is increasing and T(n) ≤ S(n), any upper bound for S(n) should also be an upper-bound for T(n).

Using the Master Theorem on S(n), we have that a = 2, b = 3/2, and c = 2. Since log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>3/2</sub> 2 = 1.709511291... < c, the Master Theorem says that this will solve to O(n<sup>2</sup>). Since S(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>), we also know that T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

We've shown that T(n) = Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) and that T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>), so T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), as required.

Hope this helps!

(By the way - (5 / 9)<sup>log n</sup> = (2<sup>log 5/9</sup>)<sup>log n</sup> = 2<sup>log n log 5/9</sup> = (2<sup>log n</sup>)<sup>log 5/9</sup> = n<sup>log 5/9</sup>. That makes it a bit easier to reason about.)

Answer (score 1):

One can't tell about runtime from the `T(n)` OR the time complexity!It is simply an estimation of running time in terms of order of input(n).

One thing which I'd like to add is :-

I haven't solved your recurrence relation,but keeping in mind that your derived relation is correct and hence further putting n=1,in your given recurrence relation,we get

```
 T(1)=T(1/3)+T(2/3)+1
```

So,either you'll be provided with the values for `T(1/3)` and `T(2/3)` in your question OR you have to understand from the given problem statement like what should be `T(1)` for Tower of Hanoi problem!

For a recurrence, the base-case is `T(1)`, now by definition its value is as following:

```
T(1) = T(1/3) + T(2/3) + 1
```

Now since T(n) denotes the runtime-function, then the run-time of any input that will not be processed is always `0`, this includes all terms under the base-case, so we have:

```
T(X < 1) = 0
T(1/3) = 0
T(2/3) = 0

T(1) = T(1/3) + T(2/3) + 1^2
T(1) = 0 + 0 + 1
T(1) = 1
```

Then we can substitute the value:

```
T(n) = n T(1) + [ (9/5)(n^2)( (5/9)^(log n) ) ]

T(n) = n + ( 9/5 n^2 (5/9)^(log n) )

T(n) = n^2 (9/5)^(1-log(n)) + n
```

We can approximate `(9/5)^(1-log(n))` to `9/5` for asymptotic upper-bound, since `(9/5)^(1-log(n)) <= 9/5`:

```
T(n) ~ 9/5 n^2 + n

O(T(n)) = O(n^2)
```

Comment: If `T(1)` is the base-case, it's highly plausible that any `T(x < 1) = 0` since having a base-case pragmatically implies that any lower term won't be processed resulting in `Time = 0`

Comment: No,I don't agree!T(1)=0 OR some constant which you can't determine directly unless some condition is given,like in Tower of Hanoi--->T(1)=1.

Comment: `T(x < 1) = 0` mean `T(1/3) = 0` and `T(2/3) = 0` giving us `T(1) = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1`